# The image I sent via my Next js app, Node js backend is not going

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am writing a next js application. My aim is to send the image I got from the frontend form, the compression ratio and the image output format to the backend (nodejs) application and return the url of the compressed image to the frontend.This is my frontend code where I get the data.

```
<form className='form-container' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className='file-img-grid'>
                <input type={"file"} accept="image/*" onChange={handleFileChange} />
              </div>
              <div className='input-range'>
                <input type="number" min={0} max={100} values={quality} onChange={(event) => setQuality(event.target.value)} />
                <span><b><u>{quality}%</u></b> How much do you want to reduce the image from there?</span>
              </div>
              <label htmlFor="imgFormat">In what format do you want the optimized image output?:</label>
              <select id="imgFormat" onChange={(event) => setFormat(event.target.value)}>
                <option value="png">png</option>
                <option value="jpg">jpg</option>
                <option value="webp">webp</option>
              </select>
              <button className='form-submit' type="submit" disabled={loading}>Submit</button>
            </form>
```

This is the piece of code where I send the data I get from the form to the rest api.

```
const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
  const [quality, setQuality] = useState(80)
  const [format, setFormat] = useState('jpeg')
  const [previewUrl, setPreviewUrl] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setLoading(true)

    // Send the image and optimization settings to the server using a POST request
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/upload', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ image, quality, format }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        // Update the preview URL with the optimized image
        setPreviewUrl(response.previewUrl)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error)
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    setImage(event.target.files[0])
  }
```

So far, no problem. When I send the data to the api, the nodejs console gives me this error [Error: Input file is missing: ]. When I debug, I see that the file information is not coming. When I debug the front side, the data is always there until I post the data. By the way, the problem is that I am successfully sending the other 2 data in the picture, backend. This surprises me as well.

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require('multer');
const sharp = require('sharp');
const fs = require('fs');
const router = express.Router();

const uploadMiddleware = multer({
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 20
    },
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(undefined, true)
    },
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, file.originalname)
        },
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, 'uploads/')
        }
    })
})

router.post("/upload", uploadMiddleware.single("image"), (req, res) => {
    const image = req.body.image;
    const format = req.body.format;
    const quality = req.body.quality;

    sharp(image)
    .resize(300, 300)
    .toFormat(format, { quality })
    .toBuffer((err, buffer) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
      } else {
        const dataURL = 'data:image/' + format + ';base64,' + buffer.toString('base64');
        res.send(dataURL);
      }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my backend code. What is your opinion on this subject?

Comment: Have you tried adding your file information into FormData?

Comment: I tried but still the same result

Comment: Can you check this link please? https://codesandbox.io/s/thyb0

Comment: https://www.hizliresim.com/h7lbtpf While file is visible when I push image useState console. When I do FormData it is empty. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I have given an answer

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we should use axios library

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', image);
formData.append('quality', quality);
formData.append('format', format);

axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/upload', formData, { headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```